# PHP Laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I dont have knowledge in laravel Blade and I have this code :

```
<span v-bind:class="{ 'total': (listing.price_per_week), 'total total-center': (!listing.price_per_week)}">@{{ listing.price_view }}*</span>
```

I want to pass that price value to this function

```
<?php echo removeFrom( @{{ listing.price_view }} ); ?>
```

but it doesnt work this way

how can pass this

Thanks

Comment: you can't execute a php function with a js input

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: do what? execute a php function with a js input?use ajax

Comment: This is not Blade. You have Vue-js and Blade in this example. So you may know that the '@' character before the `@{{ listing.price_view }}` expressions, means that this expression will not be touched or evaluated by the blade engine or renderer. Because it meant to be a model in Vue-js that could be bound with a data property in the controller or whatever Vue uses.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this out: [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a
>   given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @
>   symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should
>   remain untouched. For example:
>
> ```
> <h1>Laravel</h1>
>
> Hello, @{{ name }}.
> ```
>
> In this example, the @ symbol will be removed by Blade; however, {{
>   name }} expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing
>   it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript framework.